# Move Tabbar configuration logic to XIb

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

How is this possible?

I have taken a tabbased application
and below is the default generated code

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[GMFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GMFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[GMSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GMSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I don't want to use the code and take the logic of tabbar configuration in xib. How is this possible. Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tutorial links for this:

http://www.amateurinmotion.com/articles/2009/01/24/creating-uitabbarcontroller-based-app-using-interfacebuilder.html

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/tabbarcontroller-with-navigationcontroller-and-tableview-in-iphone/

http://mobisoftinfotech.com/iphone-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller-tutorial/

Hope this will help you